# Windows 10 Enterprise Activation for Remote Worker

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

Where I'm at, we have a Windows 10 deployment image (*.wim file) we push to all PCs. The current version of the image uses Windows 10 Enterprise x64 1803. After deployment of the image we let Windows Update run to get things up to date.

We use Enterprise Edition because Professional isn't good enough anymore if you want to avoid all the Windows Store crap *cough Candy Crush cough*.

Everything is good for most of our machines using KMS activation. However, we have one remote employee where there's a problem. He's based three states away, and is only in the office two or three times per year. One of those stretches between visits can exceed the 180-day KMS activation timeout. He also doesn't use a VPN.

My problem is I don't have a MAK key available in the Volume Licensing Service Center for Enterprise Edition. All my MAK keys are for Professional (yes, we are licensed for Enterprise).

How can I fix this? Can I apply the Professional MAK key to the Enterprise installation to automatically downgrade (I'd like to avoid this), or will I need to do a completely fresh Windows installation for just this one machine? Do I have other options?

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with VPN? He only has to connect to activate(?), so I don’t see the problem.

Comment: He doesn't use it for **anything else at all**. In fact, the current computer I'm getting ready to replace doesn't even have the connection set up properly. Thus asking him to do this is burdensome.